# Web Api - Returning a Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am unable to successfully return a populated instance of `List<StringDictionary>>` from Web API Controller to a `C#` console app. Here are the details...

Web API Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(IEnumerable<long> ids)
    {
            var results = [assume populated instance of List<StringDictionary>>]

            return Request.CreateResponse<List<StringDictionary>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, results);

    }
```

I have the following client side  code:

```
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress) })
        {

            var httpResponse = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<long[]>("api/promotions", mockIds).Result;

            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<StringDictionary>>().Result; ***** DOES NOT WORK ****

            }

        }
```

I get the following error:

```
{"Cannot create and populate list type System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary. Path '[0]', line 1, position 2."}
```

What obvious fact am I missing here?

UPDATE - what's interesting is if I change StringDictionary to Dictionary it works great.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is because of DeSerialization. JSON deserializer is not able to deserialize the format you are sending. If you just try to send single object you will get this error: `Cannot create and populate list type System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary.`

This [link](https://jsondotnet.codeplex.com/documentation) can help you getting more understanding.

Here is the JSON representation of serialized Dictionary and String dictionary.

**Dictionary**

```
[
    {
        "1": "A",
        "4": "G"
    },
    {
        "1": "A",
        "3": "B"
    }
]
```

**String Dictionary**

```
[
[
    {
        "_key": "4",
        "_value": "G"
    },
    {
        "_key": "1",
        "_value": "A"
    }
],
[
    {
        "_key": "3",
        "_value": "B"
    },
    {
        "_key": "1",
        "_value": "A"
    }
]
]
```